# Integrity Constraints - How to check whether an element doesn't appear more than once without acount operator

Tags: relational-algebra

I am learning relational algebra at the moment and I am having trouble figuring out whether it is possible to do an integrity constraint such as:

SCHEMA:
Roster(Team, Player)

Constraint:
A player can only play for one team.

Is this possible without the count operator?

I have thought about projecting Player from the Roster, which would (according to set semantics) remove all duplicates and then somehow comparing that to the Roster table, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

All help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us enough of the business requirements to help you much.

In general if you want "... only ... one ...", that sounds like a uniqueness constraint. Another name for a uniqueness constraint is a 'key' -- but this assumes you've done an analysis of the dependencies and redundancies.

I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization, then come back and clarify what you're trying to achieve.